# setState funtion is not validly updating the rows variable and hence it is not reflecting in the UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

The purpose of this is code is to similar to a ToDo List functionality. The add button is supposed to add another array object to the array of rows which is iterated by rows.map and reflected in the UI by showing another TextField . The subtract button is supposed to remove the selected row by sending its id as a parameter to a function called DeleteMetric(id). However, when the subtract button is clicked, its removing the last added array element irrespective of the id sent( Its sending the correct ID because I have console logged it and tested it out. ) I want that row to be removed whose id has been sent as a parameter and not the last added one. Thank you in advance for helping me.

This is how the state has been defined.

```
let [rows, setRows] = useState([
    {
        id: 1090,
        name: 'Enter Name',
        unit: 'Enter Unit'
    },
    {
        id: 3000,
        name: 'RISHAV',
        unit: 'Unit'
    }
]);[enter image description here][1]
```

The SubmitMetric function

```
const submitMetric = () => {
    const c = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
    const newMetric = {
        id: c,
        name: name,
        unit: unit
    }
    setRows([...rows, newMetric]);
}
```

I had the DeleteMetric function as

```
const deleteMetric = async (id) => {
    await setRows(rows.filter((element) => {
        return element.id !== id;
    }));
}
```

It was yielding the same result so I changed the function to explicitly mutating the rows variable,which also is not working.

The DeleteMetric function now.

```
const deleteMetric = async (id) => {
    rows = await rows.filter((element) => {
        return element.id !== id;
    });
    await setRows(rows);
}
```

The returned JSX.

```
return (
    <div>
        {rows.map((row) => (
            <Table>
                <TableRow>
                    <TableCell>
                        <FormControl className="form-full-width">
                            <TextField variant="outlined" defaultValue={row.id}/>
                        </FormControl>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>
                        <FormControl className="form-full-width">
                            <TextField variant="outlined" defaultValue={row.unit}/>
                        </FormControl>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell align='center'>
                        <IconButton onClick={submitMetric}>
                            <AddIcon/>
                        </IconButton>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell align='center'>
                        <IconButton onClick={async () => {
                            await deleteMetric(row.id);
                        }
                        }>
                            <RemoveIcon/>
                        </IconButton>
                    </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
            </Table>
        ))}
        <div align='center' className='margin-1'>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
                Submit
            </Button>
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not mutate the array. You modify the `rows` state when you re-assign the filtered array inside `deleteMetric()`. Try the following, it uses the state hook correctly without mutating it:

```js
const deleteMetric = (id) => {
  setRows(rows.filter((el) => el.id !== id));
}
```

You will also need to remove every async/await in your code. Non of them is necessary.

```js
function App() {
  let [rows, setRows] = React.useState([
    {
      id: 1090,
      name: "Name 1",
      unit: "Unit 1"
    },
    {
      id: 3000,
      name: "Name 2",
      unit: "Unit 2"
    },
    {
      id: 8439,
      name: "Name 3",
      unit: "Unit 3"
    }
  ]);

  const submitMetric = () => {
    const c = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
    const newMetric = {
      id: c,
      // only added these as I don't know what name 
      // and unit was in your original code
      name: `Name ${c}`,
      unit: `Unit ${c}`
    };
    setRows([...rows, newMetric]);
  };

  const deleteMetric = (id) => {
    setRows(rows.filter((el) => el.id !== id));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {rows.map((row) => (
        <table key={row.id}>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label className="form-full-width">
                  <input defaultValue={row.id} />
                </label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <label className="form-full-width">
                  <input defaultValue={row.unit} />
                </label>
              </td>
              <td align="center">
                <button onClick={submitMetric}>Add</button>
              </td>
              <td align="center">
                <button onClick={() => deleteMetric(row.id)}>Remove</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for answering the question. I had this as my function itself before and it was giving the same result. I changed the fucntion to what I have now after because I figured mutating might solve the issue but it didn't. I'll add this as an update now.

Comment: Have you removed those async/awaits too? Not sure what you wanted to achieve with those.